# (apache) how to make folder content downloadable only? (treat all files as downloadable object ONLY)

Tags: php, .htaccess

i am trying to implement a user system (PHP) where every user has a unique files folder,
the user can upload any files to that folder and download it later.

current restriction are: string of 'htaccess' inside file names is replaced with 'hhtaccesss'.
no sub folders are created.

**my question:** is there any way (.htaccess or other) to make those files for download purpose only? in order to ensure that none of those unknown files will be run on the system?

**sub question** is there any danger zip/unzip those files?

example: if the user types a direct url to a .php file, the system will not process the file(which can be harmful) and instead just 'deliver' it to the user?
same for all types of scripts/files..

Comment: you can stop php files being parsed as php via .htaccess.

Comment: but what about all other types? there are too many of them. css,js,asp... i guess more then 100. must be a way to treat all files as strange objects.

Comment: should work:  `ForceType application/octet-stream
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment` those are 2 lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in .htaccess in the appropriate directory add

```
  ForceType application/octet-stream
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
```

should force the browser to download any file no matter the type. can use `<FilesMatch ..` if you want to leave some intact.

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions would be to not expose the files directly. E.g. store them in a non-public directory and serve them through another page, e.g. `download.php`, which could read the file contents and then output and serve them with "Content-Disposition: attachment;" header.

Comment: So if i do that, can i apply (in .htaccess) 'deny from all' to all files and it will still work? if the answer is yes you solved my problem :)

Comment: this is the standard way, but i was interpreting the question slightly differently.

Comment: @Dagon yes, but the problem here is not the browser, but server executing files. I don't have enough experience with .htaccess, but say if you upload test.php and then request for it, will it execute and then give you the output as an attachment, or will it just give you back the file as attachment?

Comment: @valentinas it will just be treated as text, and not parsed via the php engine.

Comment: @Dagon +1 internet to you Sir, then ;)